# Show extra card from v-for list of cards

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to show a card with extra information for each card inside a v-for loop.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="card in cards">
        <card>
            <!-- card content with information -->
            <button @click="viewExtra" />
        </card>
        <card v-if="card.infoExtra && showExtra>
            <!-- card content with extra information -->
        </card>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            cards: [] // Array with cards and information
            ,showExtra: false 
        }),
        methods: {
            viewExtra() {
                this.showExtra = !this.showExtra;
            }
    }
</script>
```

It should only show extra card if principal card contains extra information (card.infoExtra) but it's showing for all cards that have infoExtra, not for the one on which I click the button.

Here's what I've done so far:

[image]

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `showExtra` should be seperate for each card. In mounted you can add this property in all the objects and assign the value as false. Then on click you can toggle that particular `card.showExtra`

Comment: Thanks. Same logic as in @nos-nart answer. But this is no reactive.

Comment: Sorry my understanding was wrong, As card is a custom component. No need to add a separate property in each object as each card component will contains their own scope and render separately.  I added my answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **better approach** to your question which doesn't require any **methods** and covers multiple scenarios.

```js
<div v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
  <card>
    <!-- card content with information -->
    <button @click="showExtraIndex = showExtraIndex === index && showExtraIndex !== null ? null : index" />
  </card>
  <card v-if="card.infoExtra && showExtraIndex === index">
    <!-- card content with extra information -->
  </card>
</div>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            cards: []   // Array with cards and information
            showExtraIndex: null
        }),
    }
</script>
```

**Code explanation:**

1. **[MOST IMPORTANT]** You must use `:key` while using `v-for` which acts as a unique id for each item of the array.
2. Assign the `index` of the for loop to the variable `showExtraIndex` on click of showExtra button if the value of `showExtraIndex` is null. Once the value is assigned, it will fulfill the condition added to the below card showing *extrainfo*, and on clicking the same button back, it will assign `null` value to the variable `showExtraIndex` eventually hiding the *extrainfo* card.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the gif I shared implied that I was using :key. Sorry for that.

Comment: @leandronn no problem. please choose it as your accepted answer, if you find this as best approach, so its helpful for others who visits this question.

Comment: Your approach is not working as expected. Please take a look at the link
https://tenor.com/view/gif-26265201
<md-list v-for="(offer, key) in offers" :key="key">
<md-list-item @click="toggleExtra ? toggleExtra = null : toggleExtra = key">
<!--content-->
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item v-if="toggleExtra === key">
<!--content-->
</md-list-item>
</md-list>

And in data i've declared toggleExtra: null

Comment: You are missing one condition in v-if I guess can you add that and try again?

Comment: `<md-list v-for="(offer, index) in offers" :key="offer"><md-list-item @click="toggleExtra ? (toggleExtra = null) : (toggleExtra = key)"><!--content-->
</md-list-item><md-list-item v-if="offer.infoExtra && toggleExtra === index"> <!--content--></md-list-item></md-list>` can you try this? let me know if the ternary operator works or not?

Comment: That condition is useless in the case, it's just to show only those which have extra info.

Comment: I guess ternary operator on the button click is somehow not working, and in that case we might have to unfortunately the condition on button click over the method.

Comment: toggleExtra != null ? (toggleExtra = null) : (toggleExtra = key)
this worked fine. please edit your answer with the modification so I upvote it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you should add this condition on button => `toggleExtra !== null && toggleExtra === key ? (toggleExtra = null) : (toggleExtra = key)` . Reason to update this condition is, lets assume that you clicked on 'view offers' of 1st card, now instead of clicking the 'view offers' button of the same card again, you click 'view offers` button of the 2nd card. In this scenario, it will close the 1st card's view offers box but won't open the 2nd card's view offers box. But by adding this condition it will cover this scenario as well. Please check this scenario and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it and just make sure to use `!==` instead of `!=` in your conditions

Comment: @Shreeraj I think we can simplify this statement `@click="showExtraIndex !== null && showExtraIndex === index ? showExtraIndex = null : showExtraIndex = index"` by `@click="showExtraIndex = showExtraIndex ? null : index"` ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal no, ternary operator wont work when the index value would be 0 therefore we can simplify but in this way `@click="showExtraIndex = showExtraIndex === index && showExtraIndex !== null ? null : index"`. Moreover with your simplification it wont cover a scenario which I mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: @Shreeraj Ok got it.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal it isn't working for leandronn. It was working for me as well. Also it doesn't cover other scenarios. Please go through above comment before editing the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Shreeraj Actually there is no inbuild `card` tag/element in HTML. Hence, I am sure it is a custom component and based on that I added my answer. And that is also a good practice to do. Instead of putting same card tags in multiple pages we can normally inject the common component.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I agree to your point. But here the question is about logic and functionality that how to hide and show the view offers box for multiple dynamic boxes and not about using custom component or static HTML. You can apply same logic with custom component as well. Just pass the `:card` and `:index` via props to the custom component which you showed in your answer and add `showExtraIndex` variable in that custom component and apply the same logic.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal moreover the logic covers other scenarios as well which provides better functionality to questioner.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was wrong, No need to add a separate property in each object as each card component will contains their own scope and render separately. Hence, single variable `showExtra` will work perfectly.

Here is the live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('card', {
    data() {
        return {
            showExtra: false
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div class="card">
            <p>{{ cardinfo }}</p>
            <button @click="viewExtra">View Extra</button>
            <p v-if="extrainfo && showExtra">
                {{ extrainfo }}
            </p>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['cardinfo', 'extrainfo'],
    methods: {
        viewExtra() {
            this.showExtra = !this.showExtra;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#container',
    data: {
        cards: [{
            id: 1,
            cardInfo: 'This is the content for Card 1',
            infoExtra: 'Extra infor for Card 1'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            cardInfo: 'This is the content for Card 2',
            infoExtra: 'Extra infor for Card 2'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            cardInfo: 'This is the content for Card 3',
            infoExtra: 'Extra infor for Card 3'
        }, {
            id: 4,
            cardInfo: 'This is the content for Card 4',
            infoExtra: 'Extra infor for Card 4'
        }]
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
    background: grey;
    width: 750px;
    opacity: .5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.card {
    width: 20%;
    height: 180px;
    align-self: center;
    background: whitesmoke;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    font-family: monospace;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<main id="container">
    <card v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id"
                :cardinfo="card.cardInfo" :extrainfo="card.infoExtra">
    </card>
</main>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that in my question. This is the best approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @leandronn May I know the reason of unchecked the solution ? I can help if you think this is not working as per your expectation.

Comment: Stackoverflow suggested I should change it. It still is the best approach. I’m checking it again. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Sheeraj 's approach is the best.

Comment: @leandronn It all depends how your component architecture define. There is no card element in vue. Either it should be a custom component or a component from any 3rd party library. I just phrased my answer as per the code in question. Also, for better design, I will suggest you to create a custom card component and reuse that instead of duplicating all in a single page. You can have a close look in my answer. You will get the better idea of modularization design pattern. For ex : If you want to use same functionality in some other module then as per shreeraj's code you have to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mutual `showExtra` state when you toggle it to true, all **cards** will show extra information.

You should have had `showExtra` state for individual for each card

```js
async created() {
  try {
    const response = await this.$api.getCard()
    this.cards = [...response?.data?.map(i => ({
      showExtra: false,   // attach state for each card, initially to false
      ...i,
    }))]
  } catch (err) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="card in cards">
    <card>
      <!-- card content with information -->
      <button @click="card.showExtra = true" />  <!-- toggle it -->
    </card>
    <card v-if="card.infoExtra && card.showExtra>
      <!-- card content with extra information -->
    </card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks. It nearly worked. Changing the value of the property is not working reactively. I need to make some action in the DOM to see the card.

Answer (score 0):

showExtra should be in every card object,You can't share one

Comment: same login as the other users answers. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Welcome! This seems to be a duplicate of nos art's answer (but of a lot less quality). Please delete it or make it unique.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).